# MySQL Left Joining on Limited Queries

Tags: mysql, join

I noticed a certain query I was doing on a fairly large table had become very slow when the server was under high load:

```
SELECT large.*, users.username 
FROM large
LEFT JOIN users ON large.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY large.abc 
LIMIT 30
```

(Both `large.user_id` and `users.id` are indexed.)

So upon further inspection I realized that this is due to the join query, because removing the join query made it become instant. Also, rewriting the query as this was just as fast.

```
SELECT t.*, users.username 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM large ORDER BY large.abc LIMIT 30
) as t 
LEFT JOIN users ON t.user_id = users.id
```

What is the reason for this? Is the first query joining all rows before ordering and limiting, and is the best/only way to fix this to use the second query?

Comment: your 1st query shouldn't even run because it's wrong syntax

Comment: Like @TinTran said, the syntax is wrong. You are ordering before the join.

Comment: @TinTran my mistake, fixed

Comment: what's the relationship between `large` and `users`? many to many or 1 to many or many to 1 or 1 to 1?

Comment: i am asking because i am guessing it would be slower if the order by has more rows to deal with..where the second query you're limiting down to just 30 rows before your join.

Comment: If you only need the users information that match the latest 30 records from the large table you can do, SELECT * FROM large INNER JOIN users ON users.id = large.user_id ORDER BY large.id DESC LIMIT 30 and it should be pretty fast.

Comment: @bishop another typo with the LIMIT, fixed. The ORDER BY isn't absent it's just inside the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest something and try it and let me know according to my SQL fiddle i

```
CREATE INDEX large_abc_index ON large(abc);
```

The first query seems simpler and using the right keys.
I used explain command to explain the queries here.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/784faf/1

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.
Maybe try explain command in your environment to see what it's doing

Comment: the only other think i can think of is if you indexed your large table as a two column indexed like abc and userid indexed together. this would make the 1st query slower.  At least that's what explained in sqlfiddle.com showed.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, you're joining every row in `large` to its corresponding user, ordering all the now-joined rows in `large`, and then discarding all but 30 of them. In your second query, you're ordering `large`, discarding all but 30, and then joining the `large` subset to `users`. Thus the crucial difference is how many rows are joined.

I'd like to see the query plan for these, but I suspect the second query is faster because the temporary table is readable with substantially fewer from-disk paging operations (it has only 30 rows) than the first query (it has a "large" number of rows).

Generally sub-selects are slower because they bypass the optimizer's join algorithm selection and have to rely entirely on resolving queries, but in this case because we know the sub-select has only 30 rows it seems like it's better than the built-in join optimizer.

I suspect that if you removed the `LIMIT 30` from the sub-select and put it on the outer query you'd see worse performance than your first query. But, again, the output of `EXPLAIN` would go a long way to settling this mystery.

Answer (score -2):

Try reordering your query according to this syntax http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Joins should be done before ordering.

```
   SELECT large.*, users.username FROM large LEFT JOIN users ON large.user_id = users.id ORDER BY large.abc LIMIT 30
```